# Symfony FormBuilder SetAttribute not working

Tags: forms, symfony, formbuilder

Symfony2 formBuilder setAttribute not working.

When getAttributes return right value.

But at render it doesn't take effect

like

```
$form=$this->createFormBuilder();
$form->setAttribute('name','thename');  
$form=$form->getForm();
return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Form:testingForm.html.twig',array('testingForm'=>$form->createView() ));
```

Comment: If You want set name to `form` element Yout have to do it in twig template

Comment: you can add attributes to individual fields using 'attr' => array('class' => 'tinymce') as an array item in the third parameter in the field.  There is probably a similar way to add this for the entire form.

Comment: i tried it, but it did not work on method,action and name attribute,,,,

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Neither setAttribute nor setAttributes works.

So I pass options like this:

```
$this->createFormBuilder(null, array(
    'attr' => array(
          'class' => 'delete-action-form'
    )
));
```

Check the [docs](http://api.symfony.com/2.6/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.html#method_createFormBuilder)